# Display Bitmap images from Bitmap ArrayList Android

Tags: android

I am trying to show Bitmap images stored in an ArrayList posts; However, when the code is run no images are displayed in the Fragment.

The following is my code:

```
ImageAdapter() Class

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> posts;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> posts)
    {
        mContext = c;
        this.posts=posts;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    //create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(posts.get(position));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(posts.size());
        return imageView;
    }
    }
```

A post is added to the arraylist whenever the user clicks the SUBMIT button on the portal screen as follows:

in Portal() class:

```
public void submitAction(View view)
    {
        Bitmap img = yourSelectedImage;

        if(tit==null && tit.length()==0) //not recognised
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(desc==null && desc.length()==0) //not recognised
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Description should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(img==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image should be selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {
           // Post p = new Post(tit,desc,img);
           // posts.add(p);
            posts.add(img);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, News.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

In my Fragment Class (which I want to show a gridView of images)

```
public void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflator,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Science", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        View rootView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_science_fragment,container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext(),Portal.posts));
}
```

This is the Post class (specifying data for the posts arraylist)

```
public class Post {

    private Bitmap image;


    public void setImagePath(Bitmap image)
    {
        this.image=image;
    }

}
```

And here is where I am populating the arraylist:

```
public class Portal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.StateChange";
    ImageButton imgButton;
    private static final int PICTURE_SELECTED = 1;

    static ArrayList<Bitmap> posts = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.bernine.practicalsessions.R.layout.activity_portal);
        imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.bernine.practicalsessions.R.id.imageButton1);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    public void cancelAction(View view)
    {
        this.finish(); //to prevent having too many activities on the stack rather than creating an intent to open the MainActivity class
    }

    public void submitAction(View view)
    {
        EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_title_input);
        String tit = title.getText().toString();
        EditText description = (EditText)findViewById((R.id.editText));
        String desc = description.getText().toString();
        Bitmap img = yourSelectedImage;

        if(tit==null && tit.length()==0) //not recognised
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(desc==null && desc.length()==0) //not recognised
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Description should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(img==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image should be selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {
            // Post p = new Post(tit,desc,img);
            // posts.add(p);
            posts.add(img);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, News.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    //---Method to start the intent upon clicking the imageButton---
    public void galleryIntent(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_SELECTED);
    }
    Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        BitmapFactory.Options options;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_SELECTED) {
            try {
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String mImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
                stream.close();
                //---orientation---
                try {
                    int rotate = 0;
                    try {
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                                mImagePath);
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                        switch (orientation) {
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                rotate = 270;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                rotate = 180;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                rotate = 90;
                                break;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                    yourSelectedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourSelectedImage , 0, 0, yourSelectedImage.getWidth(), yourSelectedImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);  }
                catch (Exception e) {}
                //---end of orientation---

                imgButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                imgButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image was not selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    }
 }
```

//NewsActivity()

```
public class News extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Here the viewPager is connected to the PagerAdapter class
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        //This component will be used to page between the various fragments created.
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), News.this));

        //the tabLayout is given the viewPager to connect to the pager with the tabs
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //the following was used so the tabs fill up the width of the screen being responsive for all devices and orientations
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    }

}
```

However, when the code above is run no data is being shown.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageAdapter`, you're setting the image with `imageView.setImageResource(posts.size());`

Instead you should complete the `getItem` method :

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
  return (posts.get(position));
}
```

And then, in your `getView` :

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));
```

*EDIT*
After our comments, it seems that you do not add your fragment inside your ViewPager.

Add a ViewPagerAdapter class :

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List                  fragments;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return (Fragment) this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

And then inside your NewsActivity, change as follow :

```
//This component will be used to page between the various fragments created.
List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
fragments.add(new MyFragment());
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

Comment: Where do you populate your `Portal.posts` ? Could you update your question with the full `Portal` class (or at least the relevant information), and how you populate it?

Comment: Updated it! Thanks

Comment: In the `onCreate` of your Fragment, can you log that `Portal.posts` actually contains something? From your snippets I can't see what could possibly go wrong, but I assume that `Portal.posts` is empty when you set your adapter

Comment: I believe the error lies in the onCreate of the Fragment since not even the Toast message is being shown

Comment: Oh that would also make sense. Your `submitAction` function launches the `News` activity. But does that activity actually adds the Fragment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110358/discussion-between-techworld-and-nicolas-simon).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below:

```
 public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(posts.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }
```